# How to approach putting photos( and labels and buttons) into a Scroll View, having it lengthen every time a new photo is added in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, storyboard

Right now on my Storyboard I have a View that I have a segue connecting to a scroll view. I want to make it so that the stuff  (an image, label, buttons) on the first View on the Storyboard will go to the Scrollview once the segue button is pressed.

Is there a way that when I segue into the Scroll View the Scroll View will only be the size that it needs to be to fit the newly inputted information from the first View.

Also is there a way that I can save what was put into the Scroll View so the users can add to the scroll view to make it larger. I have Firebase in my app if I need to use that to save the Scroll View information.

Below are my two view controllers (I have no view controller for my scroll view but I can make one if I need it) and a screenshot of my storyboard if that will help!

```
import UIKit

class PhotoShareViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentTextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var thatTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var thisTextField: UITextField!

    var presenter: PhotoShareModuleInterface!
    var image: UIImage!

    @IBAction func thisUploadPhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        if thisTextField.text != "" && thatTextField.text != "" {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let photoShareLabelViewController = segue.destination as! PhotoShareLabelViewController

        photoShareLabelViewController.thisString = thisTextField.text!
        photoShareLabelViewController.thatString = thatTextField.text!
        photoShareLabelViewController.imageLoaded = image
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        imageView.image = image
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func didTapCancel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        presenter.cancel()
        presenter.pop()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapDone(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        guard let message = thatTextField.text, !message.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        guard let messageOne = thisTextField.text, !messageOne.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        presenter.finish(with: image, content:message)
        presenter.dismiss()
    }
}

extension PhotoShareViewController: PhotoShareViewInterface {

    var controller: UIViewController? {
        return self
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class PhotoShareLabelViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var thisLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thatLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thisButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var thatButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var changedImage: UIImageView!

    var thisCounter = 0
    var thatCounter = 0

    @IBAction func pressedDoneButtonLabel(_ sender: Any) {
        print("done")
    }

    var presenter: PhotoShareModuleInterface!
    var imageLoaded: UIImage!

    @IBAction func pressedThisButton(_ sender: Any) {
        thisCounter += 1
        print(thisCounter)
    }

    @IBAction func pressedThatButton(_ sender: Any) {
        thatCounter += 1
        print(thatCounter)
    }

    var thisString = String()
    var thatString = String()

    @IBAction func pressedButtonDone(_ sender: Any) {
        print("done")
    }

 //   @IBAction func pressedButtonCancel(_ sender: Any) {
 //       print("cancel")
 //   }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        thisLabel.text = thisString
        thisButton.setTitle(thisString, for: UIControlState.normal)

        thatLabel.text = thatString
        thatButton.setTitle(thatString, for: UIControlState.normal)

        changedImage.image = imageLoaded
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks so much! Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Use a collectionView or a tableView .. Not a scrollView for this. https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do was practically made for a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. `UITableView` is actually a subclass of `UIScrollView` for good reason – the content keeps expanding as needed. You will need to change your data model to be an array of whatever it is you want to display, but that should be fairly easy.

Comment: how would I change my data model into an array?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but if I'm correct you have a dynamically changing amount of photos?

If that's the case I would suggest you look at CollectionViews. This will handle the scroll view size for you and help formatting.

Consider these two links
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Great tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started